# Firebase Cloud Functions return wrong value

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I‘m running following function every time a certain write happens in my Firestore database. The counter get updated like it should and also if i check the value in my Realtime Database, it shows the right value. However if i query for the value in my then(), it always returns 1. If i change my transaction to always increase the counter by 3, then it returns 3. What am I doing wrong?

```js
exports.someFunc = functions.firestore.document("/statistics/{userId}/postStats/{postId}/views/{user}/views/{view}").onCreate((event) => {
  const userId = event.params.userId
  const postId = event.params.postId

  return admin.database().ref(`/statistics/${userId}/${postId}/views`).transaction(function(current) {


         return current + 1;

       }).then(admin.database().ref(`/statistics/${userId}/${postId}/views`).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {

console.log(snapshot.val())

    );

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what's going on. But you shouldn't have to re-read the value anyway, since it's passed in to the promise as an argument. Get it with:

```
exports.someFunc = functions.firestore.document("/statistics/{userId}/postStats/{postId}/views/{user}/views/{view}").onCreate((event) => {
  const userId = event.params.userId
  const postId = event.params.postId

  return admin.database().ref(`/statistics/${userId}/${postId}/views`).transaction(function(current) {

     return current + 1;

  }).then(function(committed, snapshot) {

     console.log(snapshot.val())

  );

});
```

Comment: This gives me following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined
    at /user_code/index.js:106:27
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

Comment: Hmmm.... as far as I can see in the docs that's the correct signature of the promise resolver: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#transaction